# ANR Executing service com.example.app/com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService

Tags: android, google-analytics

Sometimes after long periods of not using my app when I try to turn it on I get an ANR. In the google play console I get the following:

```
ANR Executing service my.site.app/com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService
```

Obviously the problem is in the `AnalyticsService`. But I couldn't reproduce the ANR while my device is connected to my computer. And I don't see the ANR in the analytics account.

This is my Application class:

```
public class BaseApp extends Application {
    public static GoogleAnalytics analytics;
    public static Tracker tracker;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
        analytics.setLocalDispatchPeriod(1800);
        analytics.setDryRun(Constants.IS_DEBUG);
        GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).getLogger().setLogLevel(Logger.LogLevel.VERBOSE);

        tracker = analytics.newTracker(Constants.GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_TRACKER_ID);
        tracker.enableExceptionReporting(true);
        tracker.enableAdvertisingIdCollection(true);
        tracker.enableAutoActivityTracking(true);

        super.onCreate();
    }
}
```

And then in my BaseActivity class:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    sendScreenStat();
}

protected String getScreenStatName() {
    return getTitle().toString();
}

private void sendScreenStat() {
    BaseApp.tracker.setScreenName(getScreenStatName());
    BaseApp.tracker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());
}
```

What might be the cause?

Answer (score -2):

As the activity lifecycle methods run on the UI thread. make sure to differ operations that might take long to background threads. specifically the sendScreenStat and the tracker creation to run on background thread (AsyncTask or dedicated thread) .
See more details here: http://blog.akquinet.de/2010/02/17/android-activities-the-predominance-of-the-ui-thread/

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I would have done that if I hadn't seen the android analytics guide from the google itself: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/#tracking-methods
Specifically, they say: "getInstance(Context) is thread safe and can be called from any thread".
Actually, I use their samples of code in my project, so I expect it to work properly.